# CSS-only selection query to hide HTML element If another element has content

Tags: html, css

The CSS / HTML work I am doing is for an HTML template for eBay.  As such, I am unable to use any active content (JavaScript, etc.) which seems to be the easiest way to do this.

The software I am using that fills the template works with tags, in this case `{{PARENTIMAGEURL1}}` and `{{CHILDIMAGEURL1}}`.  When the tag is not present, the  element remains with an empty src attribute.

I need to tweak an image section of the template in such a way that if there is a parent image present, the child image is hidden.  There will always be a child image available, so the function does not need to work in reverse.

The HTML for the section is as follows:

```
<div class="main-image">
<img src="{{PARENTIMAGEURL1}}" alt="Main Image" class="img-responsive">
<img src="{{CHILDIMAGEURL1}}" alt="Main Image" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

Is it possible to use the `:empty` selector to hide the image with the child URL if the parent is present?  I'm seeing pretty limited documentation as far as how that might work with a media query.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this. The first would be to rely on the DOM structure.

### DOM structure method

You can use the CSS [+ selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) to select an element that is the very next sibling of another element: in this case, the child image.

So if there's a parent *and* child image, the child image will be hidden:

```css
.main-image img + img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Main Image" class="img-responsive">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Main Image" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

Otherwise, the selector will have no effect, and the only image you've got will show up:

```css
.main-image img + img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Main Image" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

### Attribute selection

However, if your template is going to not actually remove the parent image but simply make its source empty (i.e., `src=""`), you can get a bit more creative.

**Version one**

Here's one approach:

1. First, hide *all* parent images
2. Then, if the parent image has a source that's not empty, show it
3. If the parent image has a source that's not empty, hide the next image after it (its child image)

It's doing #2 that is the tricky part. You can use [an attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) to read the image's `src`, but you need some fragment that will be true all the time, so the style doesn't fail.

In the example below, since all the URLs are from placehold.it, I have included `img[src*="placehold"]`, but your actual solution may look something more like this:

```
img[src*=".jpg"],
img[src*=".png"],
img[src*=".gif] {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
.main-image img:nth-child(1) {
  display: none;
}
.main-image img[src*="placehold"]:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
}
.main-image img[src*="placehold"]:nth-child(1) + img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-image" style="background: firebrick">
  <img src="" alt="Parent Image" class="img-responsive">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300?text=Child+image" alt="Child Image" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="main-image" style="background: midnightblue">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300?text=Parent+image" alt="Parent Image" class="img-responsive">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300?text=Child+image" alt="Child Image" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

**Version two**

Here's another approach based on a combination of an attribute selector and the `:not` pseudo selector:

```
/* hide all parent images with no source */
.main-image img[src=""]:nth-child(1) {
  display: none;
}
/* hide all child elements following a parent element that does have a source */
.main-image img:not([src=""]) + img {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
.main-image img[src=""]:nth-child(1) {
  display: none;
}
.main-image img:not([src=""])+img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-image" style="background: firebrick">
  <img src="" alt="Parent Image" class="img-responsive">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300?text=Child+image" alt="Child Image" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="main-image" style="background: midnightblue">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300?text=Parent+image" alt="Parent Image" class="img-responsive">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300?text=Child+image" alt="Child Image" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant.  This is exactly what I was trying to do, and will be especially useful in my case.  Could this be expanded over multiple divs if the elements are given a specific ID?

Comment: @templateking Probably, but I'd have to see an example to tell you for sure. You could create a JS fiddle or similar to show me.

Comment: I'm a bit of a beginner here on Stack Overflow, not certain how to include a JS fiddle in a comment.

Comment: @templateking I just meant create one and drop a link in a comment here. Or if you want to include it as part of your question, you could edit your question, and I can edit my answer to address the updated question.

Comment: Gotcha - here's a link.  http://jsfiddle.net/q2t7uv2j/ I think that the way my template injector works, the initial solution may not work.  There's no way to delete the whole element as it stands because the tag contains only the URL, and it looks like it defaults to the alt text rather than hiding and displaying the image below it.

Comment: @templateking So basically the parent image will always be there, but sometimes its `src` might just be empty, as opposed to not having the parent image in the markup at all? Also, can you expand a bit on what you mean by expanding this over multiple divs if the elements are given specific IDs? (You could update the fiddle to include several divs with example IDs on appropriate elements.)

Comment: Yes, if a parent image is not available, the src will simply be empty. 
 In this fiddle I have covered up the empty parent section, but since the parent <img> element is still technically there, the child is hidden as well. http://jsfiddle.net/0op71j3e/

Comment: @templateking I see. I have updated my answer to show another way you could do this.

Comment: Thank you for your help and expertise.  I have tested this with my template, and it looks like this is the ticket.  I should be able to adapt this to the listing title as well, which was my other goal.

Comment: @templateking Excellent. Happy to help. In that case, unless you want to wait a day or two to see if someone comes along with another option, you can go ahead and mark this answer accepted and consider upvoting it.